# Json nulo, se esperaba un objeto pero era un string (android studio)

Tags: php, android-studio, json

Cuando intento registrar o loguear un usuario usando una base de datos (php ) en android studio obtengo el siguiente error en el logcat:java.lang.illegalstateesception expected begin_object but was string(Android Studio). Además, en el logcat puedo observar los siguientes problemas:

```
E/SystemUpdater-DataParser: [AppList] JSON : list is null No value for miuiApp. E/SystemUpdater-DataParser: [AppList] JSON : list is null. No value for listApp E/adTracker: Value 34699728403-1500805818@g.us of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject E/adTracker: Value 34633304234@s.whatsapp.net of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject E/adTracker: Value 34678292656@s.whatsapp.net of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Este es mi codigo: Constants class(en la url base tengo mi ip, el problema no es este parametro).

```
public class Constants {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/";
    public static final String REGISTER_OPERATION = "register";
    public static final String LOGIN_OPERATION = "login";
    public static final String CHANGE_PASSWORD_OPERATION = "chgPass";

    public static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    public static final String FAILURE = "failure";
    public static final String IS_LOGGED_IN = "isLoggedIn";

    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String UNIQUE_ID = "unique_id";

    public static final String TAG = "C4Growth";

}
```

Login Fragment:

```
package nutriapp.nut.nut.activities;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import nutriapp.nut.nut.Constants;
import nutriapp.nut.nut.R;
import nutriapp.nut.nut.model.RequestInterface;
import nutriapp.nut.nut.model.User;
import nutriapp.nut.nut.model.ServerResquest;
import nutriapp.nut.nut.model.ServerResponse;


import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private AppCompatButton btn_login;
    private EditText et_email,et_password;
    private TextView tv_register;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,container,false);
        initViews(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initViews(View view){

        pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);

        btn_login = (AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        tv_register = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_register);
        et_email = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_password = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_password);

        progress = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_register.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.tv_register:
                goToRegister();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_login:
                String email = et_email.getText().toString();
                String password = et_password.getText().toString();

                if(!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {

                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    loginProcess(email,password);

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), "Fields are empty !", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

        }
    }
    private void loginProcess(String email,String password){

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();


        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setContra(password);
        ServerResquest request = new ServerResquest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.LOGIN_OPERATION);
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,true);
                    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,resp.getUser().getEmail());
                    editor.putString(Constants.NAME,resp.getUser().getName());
                    editor.putString(Constants.NAME,resp.getUser().getId());
                    editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,resp.getUser().getId());
                    editor.apply();


                }
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
                Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void goToRegister(){

        Fragment register = new RegisterFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,register);
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```

Register fragment:

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment  implements View.OnClickListener{

    private AppCompatButton btn_register;
    private EditText et_email,et_password,et_name,et_altura,et_weight,et_age;
    private TextView tv_login;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register,container,false);
        initViews(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initViews(View view){

        btn_register = (AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        tv_login = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_login);
        et_name = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        et_email = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_password = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        et_weight = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_weight);
        et_altura = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_altura);
        et_age = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_age);
        progress = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.tv_login:
                goToLogin();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_register:

                String name = et_name.getText().toString();
                String email = et_email.getText().toString();
                String password = et_password.getText().toString();
                String altura = et_altura.getText().toString();
                String weight = et_weight.getText().toString();
                String age = et_age.getText().toString();

                if(!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !altura.isEmpty() && !weight.isEmpty()) {

                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    registerProcess(name,email,password,altura,weight,age);

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), "Fields are empty !", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

        }

    }

    private void registerProcess(String name, String email,String password,String altura, String weight, String age){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setContra(password);
        user.setAlt(altura);
        user.setWeight(weight);
        user.setOld(age);
        ServerResquest request = new ServerResquest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.REGISTER_OPERATION);
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
                Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void goToLogin(){

        Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,login);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User {
@SerializedName("unique_id")
private String unique_id;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("email")
private String email;
@SerializedName("old")
private String old;
@SerializedName("weight")
private String weight;
@SerializedName("alt")
private String alt;
@SerializedName("password")
private String password;
    public String getId(){
        return unique_id;
    }


    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getOld(){
        return old;
    }
    public void setOld(String old){
        this.old = old;
    }
    public String getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
    public void setWeight(String weight){
        this.weight=weight;
    }
    public String getAlt(){
        return alt;
    }
    public void setAlt(String alt){
        this.alt = alt;
    }
    public String getContra(){
        return contra;
    }

    public void setContra(String contra){
        this.contra = contra;
    }

}
```

ServerRequest class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ServerResquest {
    @SerializedName("operation")
    private String operation;
    @SerializedName("user")
    private User user;

    public void setOperation(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Retrofit class:

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Class Request interface

```
public interface RequestInterface {

    @POST("login/")
    Call<ServerResponse> operation(@Body ServerResquest request);

}
```

Php codes:

db-connect:

```
include_once 'config.php';

class DbConnect{

    private $connect;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno($this->connect)){
            echo "Fallo al conectar a la base de datos de MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }

    public function getDb(){
        return $this->connect;
    }
}

?>
```

user.php:

```
include_once 'db-connect.php';

class User{

    private $db;

    private $db_table = "t_user";

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new DbConnect();
    }

    public function isLoginExist($email, $password){

        $query = "select * from ".$this->db_table." where email = '$email' AND password = '$password' Limit 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());


            return true;

        }

        mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());

        return false;

    }

    public function isEmailUsernameExist($username, $email){

        $query = "select * from ".$this->db_table." where name = '$name' AND email = '$email'";

        $result = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    public function isValidEmail($email){
        return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false;
    }

    public function createNewRegisterUser($name, $email, $tipo, $alt, $weight, $password){

        $isExisting = $this->isEmailUsernameExist($username, $email);

        if($isExisting){

            $json['success'] = 0;
            $json['message'] = "Error al registrar. Es posible que el usuario/correo ya exista.";
        }

        else{

        $isValid = $this->isValidEmail($email);

            if($isValid)
            {
            $query = "insert into ".$this->db_table." (name, email, tipo, alt, weight, PASSWORD) values ('$name', '$email', '$tipo, $alt, $weight, '$password')";

            $inserted = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);

            if($inserted == 1){

                $json['success'] = 1;
                $json['message'] = "Usuario registrado correctamente.";

            }else{

                $json['success'] = 0;
                $json['message'] = "Error al registrar. Es posible que el usuario/correo ya exista.";

            }

            mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
            }
            else{
                $json['success'] = 0;
                $json['message'] = "Error al registrar. Dirección de correo no válida.";
            }

        }

        return $json;

    }

    public function loginUsers($username, $password){

        $json = array();

        $canUserLogin = $this->isLoginExist($username, $password);

        if($canUserLogin){

            $json['success'] = 1;
            $json['message'] = "Successfully logged in";

        }else{
            $json['success'] = 0;
            $json['message'] = "Incorrect details";
        }
        return $json;
    }
}
?>
```

index.php:

```
require_once 'user.php';

    $name = "";

    $password = "";

    $email = "";

    $tipo = "";

    $alt = "";

    $weight = "";

    if(isset($_POST['name'])){

        $username = $_POST['username'];

    }

    if(isset($_POST['password'])){

        $password = $_POST['password'];

    }

    if(isset($_POST['email'])){

        $email = $_POST['email'];

    }

    if(isset($_POST['tipo'])){

        $email = $_POST['tipo'];

    }
```

Tengo otro php llamado config en el que tengo el nombre de la base de datos, la contraseña de esta, el usuario y el host.